# UWP NTLM Authentication with Windows credentials

Tags: authentication, uwp, ntlm

There are a lot of example but all of them are working with login and password. The best what I could find with default credentials:

```
    byte[] type1Message = new byte[40]
    {
        // 'N',  'T',  'L',  'M',  'S',  'S',  'P',  '\0'
           0x4E, 0x54, 0x4C, 0x4D, 0x53, 0x53, 0x50, 0x00,
        // Type 1 message
           0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        // Flags
           0x97, 0x82, 0x08, 0xe2,
        // Supplied Domain
           0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        // Supplied Workstation
           0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        // OS Version Structure
           0x0A, 0x00, 0x39, 0x38, //0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        // Os version uknown
           0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f
    };

    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    var _client = new HttpClient(handler);
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, server.Url);
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "NTLM " + Convert.ToBase64String(type1Message));
    var message = _client.SendAsync(request);
```

Here I get only type1Message. Is there any way to get type2Message and type3Message or maybe there is a ready to go library?

Answer (score 0):

> There are a lot of example but all of them are working with login and password.

This is the *only* way that NTLM will work, unless you are on Windows and you actually use the native Windows authentication APIs ([`InitializeSecurityContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375512(v=vs.85).aspx), [`AcceptSecurityContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374707(v=vs.85).aspx), etc).

NTLM works by computing a hash of the user's logged in password, and using that as an input to create the responses to the server's challenge.  The plaintext password is required for this functionality, which is why you're seeing examples with the username and password.

So how do default credentials work then on Windows?  Well, when the user logs into the machine, that NTLM hash is generated then, from the password that they typed.  (Using Windows Hello?  That's cool, in that case the hash was generated and stored in your hardware's secure context and retrieved when you login that way.)

You won't be able to get the hash out of the operating system, so you'll need to either prompt for the username and password, and provide that to your non-native NTLM functions, or call into the native Windows functions with your language's FFI (PInvoke, JNI, etc).

Comment: Now that I see the UWP tag, it occurs to me that UWP probably _does_ have some functionality to use default credentials (but setting the header manually probably won't help matters).  I'll leave this here but I suspect that someone else can provide more concrete and functional guidance than "use `InitializeSecurityContext`.

Comment: Thank you Edward. Currently i use Windows. If I understand right, Default Credentials have to give me ability to login without user's typing login and password. This mean that some kind of System API should compute the password hash and/or take care about the whole process.

Comment: That's correct - and I _suspect_ that there's a way to do this with UWP on Windows, but I'm not very familiar with that stack.  It's rather easy with WinHttp in C or with the .NET HTTP stack.  So I suspect that there's a solution for you, and I'll happily delete this answer when someone with more knowledge provides a solution.  :)